# Unable to access S3 static website using https

Tags: ssl, https, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have followed all the steps from https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/ but my website still cannot be accessed using https.

1. My certificate was issued to the domain admin.studentqr.com successfully as displayed here
   [image: My certificate was issued successfully as displayed here]
2. My cloudfront seems to be working fine too
   [image]
   [image]
3. And I've updated my admin.studentqr.com record in Route 53 to point to the cloudfront
   [image]
4. My domain is registered under Wix, so I have the CNAME for admin.studentqr.com there pointed to my S3
   [image]

But still, I can only access http://admin.studentqr.com and not https://admin.studentqr.com

Is there anything that I still miss?

Comment: A timeout usually points toward a firewall issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how do I configure firewall for a site hosted in S3?

Comment: It seems the issue has already been resolved, is it? I see both your link is accessible.

Comment: Yes @刘宇翔 it is. I will update this question with the answer later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my domain is under Wix, I need to update the CNAME for my subdomain to point to the given ***.cloudfront.net** instead of my S3 bucket. Wait for a few minutes then if you faced the error below when accessing your site

```
403 ERROR
The request could not be satisfied.
Bad request. We can't connect to the server for this app or website at this time. There might be too much traffic or a configuration error. Try again later, or contact the app or website owner.
If you provide content to customers through CloudFront, you can find steps to troubleshoot and help prevent this error by reviewing the CloudFront documentation.
Generated by cloudfront (CloudFront)
```

try using the solution given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59693199/route53-and-cloudfront-the-request-could-not-be-satisfied

which basically make sure you add your domain/subdomain to Cloudfront Alternate Domain Names and Check Http and Https in the Cloudfront config